# Django AuthenticationForm Customization

Tags: python, django, django-widget

I am relatively new to django and want to customize the AuthenticationForm but an not sure how to do it. I essentially want to override the **init** function to be able to inject attributes and control what is displayed on the form. Specifically I would like to add this for my login form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].widget = forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control'
        })
    self.fields['password1'].widget = forms.widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control'
        })
```

My issue is that I let django do all of the work for me when creating my login view/form therefore I am unsure how to customize it. Reading the docs the LoginView uses the default AuthenticationForm.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Figured it out in case anyone else reads this from Google

urls.py for my project (added the accounts/login/ and 2 imports) -

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

from blog.forms import MyAuthenticationForm


    path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view(authentication_form=MyAuthenticationForm)),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

Then I created my own form but extended the AuthenticationForm like so:

```
class MyAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget = forms.widgets.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
        self.fields['password'].widget = forms.widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
```

Now everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class `CustomForm` which derives from `AuthenticationForm` and work on it.

You can also enforce fields to use your desired widget instead of default widget by using widget keyword argument like below:

```
<A field> =  forms.<A Field>(widget = <A Widget>(attrs = {'class': 'form-control' })
```

Comment: But then wouldn't I have to also add all of the logic for authentication, password check etc if I created a custom form? I'd prefer to not have to do that personally, if possible though haha. I simply those classes into the input fields of the already generated form

Comment: @mharre It derives from Authentication form which handles all those stuff you said. See this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm

Comment: yes thank you! I experimented a bit on my own based on a bunch of google searches and was able to figure it out by extending the base class form as you mentioned.

Comment: @mharre you're welcome. Accept my answer then. :)